# Type of array of functions that return only keys from object

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have the following object:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Then I have the following object that represents what can be updated in the backend for a user:

```
type UpdateUserBody = Pick<User, 'name'>;
```

Now I would like to have an array of functions that **ONLY** return a single property of `UpdateUserBody`.

What I have tried so far:

```
[
  () => user.name
] as Array<() => keyof UpdateUserBody>
```

The problem is that if I add `() => user.id` to the array, it doesn't throw an error:

```
[
  () => user.name,
  () => user.id,
] as Array<() => keyof UpdateUserBody>
```

### Why I have to do it in this way

I'm using Vuejs's watchers to watch these properties to save a draft of a user whenever the current logged user is creating a new user. In my watchers I'm doing:

```
const unwatchUserUpdateRequest = watch(
  [
    () => user.name,
  ] as Array<() => keyof UpdateUserBody>,
  updateUserApiRequest,
)
```

I have tried a few other small things that came to mind but nothing helped me solve the issue.

How can I allow that the array only has functions that return the properties of `UpdateUserBody`?

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyywAJgFzLphSgDmA3AUSHALYQVU0gMEC%20BAmACeABxSpRJOJAzQAQgHsSw5AF5kABWAIA1gB45UADTIA5C3ZmAfI3wEEikFWQBXTFApH1OUhTNmppYc5mZ8dg5OLjCKij4A2kzIABQAlOrWbh4AdMHGSQD0BcgAKgAWwOjIAEYQADZ1igDulGWKrnUkyGBlUM3IcCDI0H1QSWkZWdDZpAQAugNVAIJQUHDC%20hNqmboQwoowaFIyEEZKKrZAA)

Comment: The type should not be `() => keyof UpdateMeetupBody` but rather `() => UpdateMeetupBody[keyof UpdateMeetupBody]`, and even then it's not possible to force the function to return a property of the object.

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong with this question; first, `keyof` is literally the name of the key, so you're saying you only want the functions to return `"name"`.  Second, you are using type assertions (i.e., `as Array<...>`) which means you are *asserting* that the value is of that type even when it's not, and the lack of error is because the compiler thinks you know what you're doing... and you're not.  Third, there is no *type* associated with properties of `User`... any `string` can be the `name` or `id` property; tagging values as coming from particular property accesses is not supported.

Comment: What even is `user` here?  This isn't a [mre] suitable for others to modify in their own IDE.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for the feedback. I thought that something like this would be possible but unfortunately it doesn't look like it. The `user` can be seen in the playground. I haven't included it here since it is infered by the interface `User`

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the callback signatures? If yes, you could change it like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyywAJgFzLphSgDmA3AUSHALYQVU0gMEC+BAmACeABxSpRJOJAzQAQgHsSw5AF5kABWAIA1gB45UADTIA5C3ZmAfI3wEEikFWSthRikfU5SFM2dNLDnMzPjsHJxcYRUUKAAo4gFdMKE8pGQgjJRUASnVrSmo6HIBtAF1vEqZkRPyagDog42qAehbkABUAC2B0ZAAjCAAbIcUAd0ouxUShkmQwLqhx5DgQZGglqGratQLE+tJm-DK7R2cwZDGZBC7odHi4vN3C7lpSio1oxXrWOFE4hBwEb9RC6OqPOqA4GguJuIw5HIEIA) and then map it to match the required Vue callback signatures. That's a little overhead though for the type safety

Comment: @A_A Thank you for the answer. Yeah, that seems a bit overkill. I think that the best approach here (since it's not possible to do what I'm looking for) is to simply add a comment explaining what this is suppose to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that `user.id` is not accessible, you will need to modify the user type. An easy way to do this is to create the functions in a different scope and pass the `user` as a parameter:

```js
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

type UpdateUserBody = Pick<User, 'name'>;

function getUserUpdateWatchers(user: UpdateUserBody): (() => string)[] {
  return [
    () => user.name,
    () => user.id, // Property 'id' does not exist on type 'UpdateUserBody'.
  ]
}

const unwatchUserUpdateRequest = watch(
  getUserUpdateWatchers(someUser),
  updateUserApiRequest,
)
```

If you only want to extract keys without further functionality, you could also use a list of keys with a generic function that maps the keys to `() => user[key]` functions:

```js
const unwatchUserUpdateRequest = watch(
  // Type '"id"' is not assignable to type '"name"'.
  toPropertyExtractors<UpdateUserBody>(['name', 'id'], user),
  updateUserApiRequest,
)

function toPropertyExtractors<T>(keys: (keyof T)[], object: T): (() => T[keyof T])[] {
  return keys.map(key => () => object[key])
}
```